# (Linq & EF) Where MyType = (int)Enum does not work

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a database in Azure that I created from scratch (not using code first in EF) and made a column in one of my tables to represent an Enum from my C# classes.

**The enum is**

```
 public enum ItemType
{
    Build,
    Stock,
    Shell,
    Parts,
    [Display(Name="All Vehicles")]
    AllTypesOfVehicles
}
```

I am trying to select certain records in an EF Linq Query by using this enum in the where clause. I simply cast the enum to its underlying int32 data type but it does not retrieve me the results I want.

```
 var results = context.Items.Include(P => P.Manufacturer)
                    .Include(P => P.Category).Include(P => P.VehicleMake)
                    .Include(P => P.VehicleModel).Include(P => P.VehicleYear);

//Fetches specific type of item
if (TypeOfPart != StaticData.ItemType.AllTypesOfVehicles)
{
    results.Where(P => P.Type == (int)TypeOfPart); //This does not work
}
else //fetches all vehicle types
{
    results.Where(P => P.Type == 0 | P.Type == 1 | P.Type == 2);
}
```

Is this expected in EF? I know EF supports Enum from a code first approach but I don't see why this would cause a problem. I went into my Azure portal and wrote a manual query to see if I would get the results that I wanted and I did.

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Type = 2
```

This yielded me only results that were of enum type "Shell". Even hardcoding the number 2 into the where clause in my EF query does not get me the results I want. I rechecked my code to make sure I wasn't overriding that where clause anywhere else and everything seems clean. Just to be sure I even called .ToList() right after the where clause but still got bad results.

I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here???

============Edit after first answer=======================

```
 var results = context.Items.Include(P => P.Manufacturer)
                    .Include(P => P.Category).Include(P => P.VehicleMake)
                    .Include(P => P.VehicleModel).Include(P => P.VehicleYear);

                //Fetches specific type of item
                if (TypeOfPart != StaticData.ItemType.AllTypesOfVehicles)
                {
                    var part = (int)TypeOfPart;
                    results.Where(P => P.Type == part);
                    List<Item> t = results.ToList();
                }
                else //fetches all vehicle types
                {
                    results.Where(P => P.Type == 0 | P.Type == 1 | P.Type == 2);
                }
```

[image: Wrong results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to assign `results.Where()` back to `results` to get it work and try performing the cast outside EF query context:

```
//Fetches specific type of item
if (TypeOfPart != StaticData.ItemType.AllTypesOfVehicles)
{
    var part = (int)TypeOfPart;
    results = results.Where(P => P.Type == part ); //This does not work
}
else //fetches all vehicle types
{
    results = results.Where(P => P.Type == 0 | P.Type == 1 | P.Type == 2);
}
```

And btw, should you just skip the `P.Type` related `Where` when you're trying to fetch all types of vehicles? It would mean you don't need `else`.

```
//Fetches specific type of item
if (TypeOfPart != StaticData.ItemType.AllTypesOfVehicles)
{
    var part = (int)TypeOfPart;
    results.Where(P => P.Type == part ); //This does not work
}
```

Comment: No. I have vehicles and Items in the same table. They share all the same columns. I differentiate between them by using that enum so 0-2 are different vehicle types while 3 is items (car parts) and 4 (is never saved in the db) just signifies to select parts with enum values 0-2. I updated my question according to your answer. As you can see in the screen shot the part variable is holding 0 but yet my first entity has a `Type` value of 1. I also called to list immediately after the where clause to eliminate any possible code hiccups.

Comment: OK, I see where the problem is. `results.Where()` does not edit `results` - it returns new query with additional condition. You have to assign it back to `results` to get it work.

Comment: **Face Palm** You're awesome.